# What are the Pitfalls of Using Static JSON Files for Frontend Data?

Tags: json, database, rest, web, backend

Let's say I have some data, `members`. Each `member` has a `name:string`, `birthYear:number`, `favoriteBook:string`, and an `id:number`.

I make a JSON file that includes all the `members` along with each `member`'s data. The JSON file would be deployed along with the HTML, CSS, and JS of the site. The scripts would include and parse the json, then display in HTML. If I wanted to make changes to the data, I would update the JSON and redeploy using cache controls to assure users receive the latest data.

What pitfalls would arise from using a static JSON file that I parse and display, instead of a traditional REST API?

Off the back my concern would be scale, but if I don't intend to have too much data, would this be a problem? In that case, what would be my limitations?

Comment: If you have to redeploy anyway, why not just hard code the data right in your script files?

Comment: if your website is static and the json data is not big then there is no need to store the data inside the database and access it via rest (because it will affect the performance). But if your data is large and there are frequent changes then I would say go for the rest option because modifying data may be easier.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I would argue simplicity. I could create a form that would make updating the JSON file easy. Rather that having to update an object in code. Either way, they're pretty much doing the same thing. Would hardcoding an object with all your data run you into any pitfalls over using a REST Api instead?

Comment: A REST API is more about the full CRUD lifecycle. If all you're doing is the R, it's not really an API so much as HTTP GETs in an organized manner, and you can do that with just JSON files. As far as scalability, JSON files have the same scalability as any other asset, like HTML or CSS files.

Comment: Why not use json data files on a separate repo and call it via ajax in the website. If You do so, You no need redeploy, a commit on data repo and go. In the future repo can be replaced by rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data tend to change pretty often you will probably face some performance loss. In this case I would recommend you to use a regular database.

On the other hand, if your data won't be updated/changed regularly your solution could work and it's also pretty easy to implement ... But I won't recommend it.

Hope this helps !

Ronaiim

Comment: Why you won't recommend it for non changing data?